# Javascript: access parental function's variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope

I have the following code (simplified):

```
function(req, res) {
  var path = 'login';

  req.on('end', function(data) {
    var post = parsevars(rawpost, '&');
    if (typeof post.username !== 'undefined' && typeof post.password !== 'undefined') {
      if (handlelogin(post.username, post.password))
        path = req.url;
    }
  });
}
```

The bold part is what doesn't work as expected :/
Any input on how to escape this scope restriction would be great.

Comment: and what is the expected behavior? do you `leak` the `path` in some other closures where you expect it to change when the `end` fires? otherwise I don't see how it would matter for the outer function that declared it.

Answer (score 2):

It DID work, the code after it was just executed BEFORE the event handler.

Comment: Welcome to the async world :)

Answer (score 0):

Odd, that *should* work since `req` is in the outer scope of the closure.

However I think you'll find that the current `req` is also available as `this` within the callback, i.e.:

```
path = this.url;
```

Comment: Like your edit says, this should work, I very much doubt changing the name of the reference will have an effect. In fact, if it does we should be more worried. Most likely cause: The OP's bug, although with zero information there's not much that can be done.